# Magento 2.3, admin grid uiComponent is not showing the value from table

Tags: magento-2.3

I have a custom table and a custom module, A grid etc, which are already created.
Now I want to include one of my table column to the Grid listing page.
Column name : entity
which contains either 0041 or 0030 as values for all rows.

I want to include this field to the page and also add entity fied to the grid also as a select field.

Following is my code for that;

```
<column name="entity" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <options class="Acer\RsaDoa\Model\Source\Entity"/>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <sortable>false</sortable>
                <label translate="true">Entity</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
```

Acer\RsaDoa\Model\Source\Entity.php here

```
<?php

namespace Acer\RsaDoa\Model\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class Entity implements OptionSourceInterface
{   
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        $options[] = ['label' => '0041', 'value' => 0041];
        $options[] = ['label' => '0030', 'value' => 0030];
        return $options;
    }
}
```

[image: It is ok in filter]
but in the column it is all empty : [image]

When I change the settings to text/string instead of select, it is all working fine.. What did I miss here??
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the mistake myself.

```
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        $options[] = ['label' => '0041', 'value' => '0041'];
        $options[] = ['label' => '0030', 'value' => '0030'];
        return $options;
    }
```

added ' ' for the values